# How to run a Python script every day in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I have a simple script, it retrieves data from an API and loads it into BigQuery. I was using Cloud Functions and it was running smoothly, however there came a time that reached the 9-minute run time limit.

What is the best way to do this in GCP, taking the time the script needs? I was thinking of creating another Cloud Function that daily starts a preemtible VM, the VM executes the script and in the end turns itself off. To keep the price low, the VM would always shut down at the end of the data load. It would start the next day at the selected time.

I don't know where to start to do this, but I was wondering if that would be the best way.

Comment: Why not use a cron job?

Comment: A GCP cron job using Cloud Scheduler? I already use it today to activate the Cloud Function. Would I use it to start the function that creates, executes and turns off the VM? I was thinking that way, I just wasn't sure if it was really the ideal. Thanks!

Comment: You can look into using a [Google compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) VM as well. IIRC you can get a f1-micro instance for free from GCP. If your script has high memory requirements, you may need a larger instance though.

Comment: I'll go with the VM on Compute Engine. Thanks! I will look for a way to create it, run the Python script and shut it down daily.

Comment: How long run your script? How memory it use? Does it use multicpu? Does it need persistent disk?

Comment: In addition to Guillaume questions above - do you have any requirements for uniqueness/deduplication? and the process state control? monitoring?

Comment: The script will be running for 4 hours. The VM can be a preemtible e2-micro (without persistent disk). No requirements for uniqueness/deduplication or process state control. The monitoring only to check if the VM is turned off/removed after the execution, I think. The script is extremely simple, just the runtime that cause some problem to Cloud Functions, due to the amount of data.

Comment: You can use cloud functions to provision the VM along with `start-script` or [`start-script-url`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) (recommended) that includes setting up environment and then running the bigquery ingestion job and end it will end. The VM code then contains scraping, ingestion logic along with current VM destroy. To get the current VM, you can use [VM metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview).

Answer (score 1):

Cloud functions aren't really suited to batch jobs that may be longer running than 10 minutes. I'd suggest running your job using a Compute Engine VM and scheduling it with a combination of Cloud functions / Cloud scheduler.

Here's a rough outline:

1. Set up a containerized Compute Engine VM.
2. Create a Cloud function to start the VM on a pub-sub trigger.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

def start_job(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
    compute.instances().insert(
        project='project_id',
        zone='us-east1-b',
        body=vm_config).execute()
```

3. Create a Cloud Scheduler to trigger the pub-sub according to your schedule.

This lets you avoid the cost of an always-on VM. See this [blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/running-a-serverless-batch-workload-on-gcp-with-cloud-scheduler-cloud-functions-and-compute-86c2bd573f25) for more detail.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
import schedule
import time

def run_daily():
    do something
    do something else        


schedule.every().day.at("08:20:30").do(run_daily) # HH MM SS

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! At first I was thinking about making the VM shut down after loading the data (sorry, I just included this information in the post, it was missing). That is, the VM would only be active for the necessary time (or a predetermined time). But if I don't find a simple solution, I will do it the way you demonstrated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented following approach.

1. Create a VM
2. Setup up instance schedule (for effective utilisation of VM)
3. setup cron job to run the script daily.

Warda Rahim's [blog](https://medium.com/@wardarahim25/automate-your-script-using-gcp-vm-instance-and-cron-job-c2a5080eba76) helped me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35761514)